# software installation problem in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

"wine" software installation problem in ubuntu 12.04.
the problem is=>The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4-0ubuntu5~precise1~ppa1) but 1.4-0ubuntu5~precise1~ppa1 is to be installed
plz help me.........

Answer (score 0):

You may check newest version of Wine. Im using Wine 1.5.6.

Installation process. Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and paste this command:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install wine1.5
    sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Enjoy!

Comment: plz tell me elaborate.....i am 1st user

Comment: open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and paste above command line by line and follow the instruction.

Comment: i do this but there show a problem.i.e =>Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 95, in run
    self.add_ppa_signing_key(self.ppa_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in add_ppa_signing_key
    print "Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, e[1])
NameError: global name 'lp_url' is not defined

Comment: plz plzzzzz help me

Comment: i suggest you report bugs to ubuntu. I've no problem installing this package.